# Publishing ASP.NET Core MVC Application to IIS - 404 not found

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Can I get some ideas on this.

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC application that runs fine in VS 2015. No problems
I tried to publish it and use it in IIS, the first time I did this last night it worked, no problems, yay.

But I come in this morning, make 1 change to an image location, still works in VS, publish it again and try IIS, 404. I set the site back and publish again, 404.
Simply not working any more, does anyone know whats up.

The one and only static page is still working if I browse to it so the site can be hit, it just looks like its ignoring the routes now??

Comment: Also please note, in wwwroot it is not placing the web.config. Last night when I first tried it error ed, I added web,config from one folder up and it worked but this still doesn't work now.

Comment: Try deleting the publish folder in IIS and re-publish.

Comment: Please, don't use MVC6 tags anymore. It's for a future version of ASP.NET MVC based on the old webstack (MVC5). ASP.NET Core is a complete new and incompatible, portable version based on .NET Core. Use [tag:asp.net-core-mvc] and/or [tag:asp.net-core] tags instead and your question is more likely to be found by people who can help you with the issue